# std::to_array for multi dimensional array

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++20, stdarray, function-templates

C++20 added [`std::to_array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/to_array) so you can easily create `std::array` from a C-Style array, for example:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
void foo(const T (&a)[N]) {
    auto arr = std::to_array(a);
}
```

But, `std::to_array` does not support two-dimensional arrays, so the following will not work:

```
auto arr = to_array({1, 2}, {3, 4});
```

Can this be manually implemented?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It can be implemented. And the following can work:

```
constexpr auto a = to_array({1, 2}, {4, 5, 6});
// ^ std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 2>
constexpr auto b = to_array("nice", "thing");
// ^ std::array<std::array<char, 6>, 2>
```

Here is [the code](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/fMfG83oTz):

```
template <typename T, std::size_t... N>
constexpr auto to_array(const T(&... arr)[N]) {
    constexpr size_t COLS = detail::max<N...>();
    return detail::to_2d_array_from_pack<sizeof...(N), COLS>(arr...);
}
```

With the following helpers:

```
namespace detail {

template <std::size_t N1, std::size_t... Ns>
constexpr size_t max() {
    if constexpr(sizeof...(Ns) == 0) return N1;
    else {
        constexpr size_t max_rest = max<Ns...>();
        return N1 > max_rest ? N1: max_rest;
    }
}

template <std::size_t TargetSize, typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... I>
constexpr auto to_array(std::index_sequence<I...>, const T (&arr)[N]) {
    return std::array<T, TargetSize>{arr[I]...};
}

template <std::size_t TargetSize, typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto to_array(const T(&arr)[N]) {
    return to_array<TargetSize>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, arr);
}

template <std::size_t TargetRows, std::size_t TargetCols, typename T, std::size_t... N>
constexpr auto to_2d_array_from_pack(const T(&... arr)[N]) {
    using TargetType = std::remove_cv_t<T>;
    return std::array<std::array<TargetType, TargetCols>, TargetRows> {to_array<TargetCols>(arr)...};
}

} // end of namespace detail
```

---

Above supports only 2D arrays. To support 3D arrays [we can add](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/KrhqGEoT3):

```
template <typename T, std::size_t... N, std::size_t... M>
constexpr auto to_array(const T(&... arr)[N][M]) {
    constexpr size_t Y_SIZE = detail::max<N...>();
    constexpr size_t Z_SIZE = detail::max<M...>();
    using TargetType = std::remove_cv_t<T>;
    return std::array<std::array<std::array<TargetType, Z_SIZE>, Y_SIZE>, sizeof...(N)> {
        detail::to_2d_array_from_array_of_arrays<Y_SIZE, Z_SIZE>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, arr)...
    };
}
```

With the following helper in namespace `detail`:

```
template <std::size_t TargetRows, std::size_t TargetCols, typename T,
  std::size_t N, std::size_t M, std::size_t... I>
constexpr auto to_2d_array_from_array_of_arrays(std::index_sequence<I...>, const T (&arr)[N][M]) {
    return to_2d_array_from_pack<TargetRows, TargetCols>(arr[I]...);
}
```

Comment: You forgot the `...std::size_t... Ns` with `const T(&...arr)...[Ns]` step.  (I kid)